# Need a javascript function to reset text to black on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing an exam entry form to take a users name, subject, exam number and level (GCSE, AS, A2), if the user inputs a value wrong then the name of the field turns red, I need a JavaScript function to change the text back to black and i am having some trouble with this. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Exam Entry</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function validateForm() {
        var result = true;
        var msg="";

        if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter your name \n";
            if(result) document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
            document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
            result = false;
        }

        if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
            if(result) document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
            result = false;
        }

        if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter the exam number \n";
            if(result) document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
            document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
            result = false;
        }

        if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.length!=4) {
            msg+="Your exam number must be exactly 4 digits \n";
            if(result) document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
            document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
            result = false;
        }

        if(msg != ""){
            alert(msg);
            return result;
        }

        var checked = null;
        var inputs = document.getElementsByName('examtype');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].checked) {
                checked = inputs[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if(checked==null) {
            alert('Please choose an option');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return confirm('You have chosen '+checked.value+' is this correct?');
        }

    }


</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
    <form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
      <table width="50%" border="0">
                <tr>
                                <td id="name">Name</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder='Name' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td id="subject">Subject</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="subject" placeholder='Subject' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td id="examnumber">Exam Number</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="examnumber" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder='No.'/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td><input type="radio" id="examtypeGCSE" name="examtype" value="GCSE" /> : GCSE<br/>
                                <input type="radio" id="examtypeA2" name="examtype" value="A2" /> : A2<br/>
                                <input type="radio" id="examtypeAS" name="examtype" value="AS"/> : AS<br/>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
                                <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you heard about `else`? if (...) { red } else { black } And most developers would be toggling a class.

Comment: `document.getElementById('name').style.color="black";`

Comment: If you set a property of `style` to `''` it uses the default value

Comment: Your current code turns the text red with this: `document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";`.  Can you guess how you would turn the text black?

Comment: Sorry I should have worded question better, I understand that you would just use the same code as above but with black however when I created a function to do this it did not work, how would I correctly write a separate function to change the text colour?

Answer (score 0):

In beginning of the function validateForm() set all the texts to black. Cuz everytime you enter the validate function it will set all the texts to black, then enter the if statements if the conditions is correct.

for example:

```
function validateForm() {
document.getElementById('name').removeAttribute('style');
....
....
...
}
```

but then the color wont change until you click the button.

Else add an onchange function on the textboxes to check the validation.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however the function name to change the names back is the same as the one to validate the entire form, should i change this to something like 'resetNames'? Or leave it how it is

Comment: You should only take "document.getElementById('name').removeAttribute('style');" and put it at the top of your excistin function, and also ad a row for every element you have so the same code but insted of name set subject and so on.